# How to convert an array of objects (of different lengths) into one object that has different properties from the elements in the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make an app that uses data from the flickr api (I'll be only using the open license images and crediting the author, etc.). I'm querying the flickr api and then parsing the results into one row about each item I'm searching for. Basically, I want each row to have the name of the thing I'm searching for and then the image link + the image author like so: [image]

But because the api results are different (sometimes flickr gives me 1 image in the results, sometimes there are hundreds) , I can't think of an elegant way to convert the array of objects into one object. I'm basically doing a transpose from rows to columns. Because the array lengths are different, I ended up using a bunch of horrendous `if else` clauses to get this done.

```
// slicing the first 5 elements from flickr results
let first5elements = data.photos.photo.slice(0, 5);

let photos_with_query = [];

if (first5elements.length === 0) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
  };

  console.log(onerowforecoregions);
  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
} else if (first5elements.length === 1) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
  };

  console.log(onerowforecoregions);
  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
} else if (first5elements.length === 2) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
    image_2: first5elements[1].url_c,
    image_author_2: first5elements[1].pathalias,
  };

  console.log(onerowforecoregions);
  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
} else if (first5elements.length === 3) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
    image_2: first5elements[1].url_c,
    image_author_2: first5elements[1].pathalias,
    image_3: first5elements[2].url_c,
    image_author_3: first5elements[2].pathalias,
  };

  console.log(onerowforecoregions);
  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
} else if (first5elements.length === 4) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
    image_2: first5elements[1].url_c,
    image_author_2: first5elements[1].pathalias,
    image_3: first5elements[2].url_c,
    image_author_3: first5elements[2].pathalias,
    image_4: first5elements[3].url_c,
    image_author_4: first5elements[3].pathalias,
  };

  console.log(onerowforecoregions);
  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
} else if (first5elements.length === 5) {
  let onerowforecoregions = {
    region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name,
    image_1: first5elements[0].url_c,
    image_author_1: first5elements[0].pathalias,
    image_2: first5elements[1].url_c,
    image_author_2: first5elements[1].pathalias,
    image_3: first5elements[2].url_c,
    image_author_3: first5elements[2].pathalias,
    image_4: first5elements[3].url_c,
    image_author_4: first5elements[3].pathalias,
    image_5: first5elements[4].url_c,
    image_author_5: first5elements[4].pathalias,
  };

  photos_with_query.push(onerowforecoregions);
}
```

This does work...but it's as far from elegant as you can get. So I'm wondering is there a way to take an array of objects and transpose it to be just one object with multiple properties from the original object properties. Something where it would automatically pull off image_1, image_10, etc.?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use an object with countable properties (image1, image2), use an array for that. But if you still want to map it, you can loop through the array and assign the values to dynamically generated object keys: `array.forEach((item, index) => object['image_' + index] = item);` You can also use `reduce()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map each item in `first5Elements` to an array of entries, taking the index of the item being iterated over to determine the key. For example, if the input array contains only

```
{ url: { c: 'url' }, pathalias: 'path' }
```

it can be transformed into the entries

```
[['image_1', 'url'], ['image_author_1', 'path']]
```

With `flatMap` and `Object.fromEntries` you can then concisely turn that into the object you want:

```
const first5elements = data.photos.photo.slice(0, 5);
const entries = first5elements.flatMap(
    (item, i) => [
        ['image_' + (i + 1), item.url.c],
        ['image_author_' + (i + 1), item.pathalias]
    ]
);
const photos_with_query = [
    { region_name: ecoregion.us_l4name, ...Object.fromEntries(entries) }
];
```

Live snippet:

```js
const first5elements = [{ url: { c: 'url' }, pathalias: 'path' }];
const entries = first5elements.flatMap(
    (item, i) => [
        ['image_' + (i + 1), item.url.c],
        ['image_author_' + (i + 1), item.pathalias]
    ]
);
const photos_with_query = [
    { region_name: 'ecoregion.us_l4name', ...Object.fromEntries(entries) }
];
console.log(photos_with_query);
```